# mongodb date aggregation operators timezone adjustments with php

Tags: php, mongodb, date, timezone, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to adjust the timezone with date aggregation operators. 
I need to make -7 hours adjustment on the `$signs.timestamp` field.

This is my code:

```
function statsSignatures() {
    $cursor = $this->db->collection->users->aggregate(
        array('$unwind' => '$signs'),
        array('$project'=>array(
            'signs'=>'$signs',
            'y'=>array('$year'=>'$signs.timestamp'),
            'm'=>array('$month'=>'$signs.timestamp'),
            'd'=>array('$dayOfMonth'=>'$signs.timestamp'),
            'h'=>array('$hour'=>'$signs.timestamp')
        )),
        array('$group'=>array(
            '_id'=>array('year'=>'$y','month'=>'$m','day'=>'$d','hour'=>'$h'),
            'total'=>array('$sum'=>1)
        )),
        array('$sort'=>array(
            '_id.year'=>1,
            '_id.month'=>1,
            '_id.day'=>1,
            '_id.hour'=>1
        ))
    );
    return $cursor['result'];
}
```

I'm using MongoDB version 2.6.3.

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Yes, time zone issues can often be challenging.  However, as it is currently written, it's difficult to tell what you are asking.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center, then come back and edit your question.  Thanks.

Comment: $signs.timestamp is mongodate object. I need to adjust it -7 hours before grouping

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Have you consider that many time zones follow different offsets during daylight saving time?  For example, US Mountain Time (except for most of Arizona) is -7 during standard time and -6 during daylight time.

Comment: well, if i'm not adjusting that - he's doing timezone 0 and data grouping and extracting is totally wrong

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following you at all.  If you could please read the help center links I gave you and *edit your question accordingly*, then perhaps you will get more direct answers from myself and others.  Christian's answer looks good, but I'm not even sure if that's what you need to know or not.

Comment: Also note that commentary about how much time you've wasted and notes like "it's outdated" or "it's not working" doesn't help yourself or anyone else.  Please write your question so it can be a useful resource to others who may have the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$project` with [$subtract](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/#exp._S_subtract) operator to make a -7 hour adjustment to a Date field:

```
{
    $project : { 
        ts : { $subtract : [ "$signs.timestamp", 25200000 ] }
    }
}

// 25200000 == 1000 milis x 60 sec x 60 mins x 7 h
```

The projected field `ts` is a Date that's offset by -7 hours.

**Edit**

This is the correct PHP syntax when using $subtract.

```
array(
    '$project' => array( 
        'ts' => array('$subtract' => array('$signs.timestamp', 25200000))
    )
)
```

Subtract accepts an array of values, not a key=>value pair.

Comment: code:
array('$project' => array(
                    'ts' => array('$subtract' => array(
                        '$signs.timestamp' => 25200000
                    ))
                ))

I'm getting exception "exception: invalid operator '$signs.timestamp'"

Comment: theoretically this is right answer.but I have tried so many ways to do that on php and it's not working.

Comment: Thank you ! Banging my head on the table ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but I'm getting "exception: invalid operator '$signs.timestamp'" if i'm trying to subtract this in php like this code:

```
        $cursor = $app['mdb']->changemi->users->aggregate(
            array('$unwind' => '$signs'),

            array('$project' => array(
                'ts'=>array('$subtract'=>array(
                    '$signs.timestamp'=> 25200000
                ))
            )),
            array('$project'=>array(
                'y'=>array('$year'=>'$ts'),
                'm'=>array('$month'=>'$ts'),
                'd'=>array('$dayOfMonth'=>'$ts'),
                'h'=>array('$hour'=>'$ts')
            )),
            array('$group'=>array(
                '_id'=>array('year'=>'$y','month'=>'$m','day'=>'$d','hour'=>'$h'),
                'total'=>array('$sum'=>1)
            )),
            array('$sort'=>array(
                '_id.year'=>1,
                '_id.month'=>1,
                '_id.day'=>1,
                '_id.hour'=>1
            ))
        );
```

So I came with 2 workarounds:

1. backend php. json_decode

   ```
       $cursor = $app['mdb']->changemi->users->aggregate(
           array('$unwind' => '$signs'),
           json_decode('{"$project" : {"ts" : { "$subtract" : [ "$signs.timestamp", 25200000 ] }}}',true),
           array('$project'=>array(
               'y'=>array('$year'=>'$ts'),
               'm'=>array('$month'=>'$ts'),
               'd'=>array('$dayOfMonth'=>'$ts'),
               'h'=>array('$hour'=>'$ts')
           )),
           array('$group'=>array(
               '_id'=>array('year'=>'$y','month'=>'$m','day'=>'$d','hour'=>'$h'),
               'total'=>array('$sum'=>1)
           )),
           array('$sort'=>array(
               '_id.year'=>1,
               '_id.month'=>1,
               '_id.day'=>1,
               '_id.hour'=>1
           ))
       );
   ```
2. frontend javascript (minusHours)

   ```
   Date.prototype.minusHours= function(h){
       this.setHours(this.getHours()-h);
       return this;
   }
   ```

...

```
            "date": new Date({{ i._id.year }}, {{ i._id.month -1 }}, {{ i._id.day }}, {{ i._id.hour }}, 0, 0, 0).minusHours(7),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. Instead of doing the timezone conversion in the 'project', I just convert the timestamp while grouping.

```
group._id = { 
    year: { $year : [{ $subtract: [ "$timestamp", 25200000 ]}] }, 
    month: { $month : [{ $subtract: [ "$timestamp", 25200000 ]}] }, 
    day: { $dayOfMonth : [{ $subtract: [ "$timestamp", 25200000 ]}] }
};

group.count = { 
    $sum : 1
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to close some objects in array, this way worked for me:

```
group._id = { 
    year: { $year : { $subtract: [ "$timestamp", 25200000 ]}}, 
    month: { $month : { $subtract: [ "$timestamp", 25200000 ]}}, 
    day: { $dayOfMonth : { $subtract: [ "$timestamp", 25200000 ]}}
};

group.count = { 
    $sum : 1
};
```